# CSS max-width: 100% for IE 6 with expression?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, css

I have this css:

```
.container img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
 }
```

Now I need this working for IE 6.

I know you can do:

```
 width: expression(this.width > xxx ? xx : true);
```

but xxx needs to be a number, not a percentage I believe.

I'm doing max-width: 100% so that the width of the image will not exceed the width of the .container

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having tested it, I guess you need to compare the elements (client) width to its parent's. Something like:

```
width: expression(this.clientWidth > this.parentNode.clientWidth ? this.parentNode.clientWidth + "px" : this.clientWidth + "px");
```

Comment: Well, I need the closest .container, this can be parent > parent > parent or parent > parent or just parent, but I don't know the relationship.

Comment: In that case, could you give more details. What is the effect you want to achieve? How does the HTML look like? A working example would helpful.